# Is it possible to use base64 code to replace a sound file used in HTML?

Tags: javascript

I want to save a request by putting the sound file information into a .js file just like people convert images into base64 texts.

Is it possible to do the same for sound?

Comment: looks like it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762763/play-wav-sound-file-encoded-in-base64-with-javascript

Comment: Yep, that works in all modern-ish browsers.

Comment: Possible – yes. Reasonable due to the sheer amount of space base64 takes compared to a compressed audio file – questionable.