# Register a sound already loaded as a base64 or binary in soundjs library

Tags: createjs, soundjs

I have a big problem, I have not found a solution yet for.
In short I have a front end web page where a custom API build on the fly audio tracks. 
All the tracks are temporarily stored in a variable within the browser as base64 strings. My problem is that i would like to register these sounds in createjs to manage them easily. 
How could I register sounds in soundjs by using audio base64 content rather than a path, that doesn't exists because the page is state less.

As a simple example:

```
var audioTrack = "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"
createjs.Sound.registerSound([src], "audioTrack"); // HOW CAN I USE THIS FUNCTION TO REGISTER MY STRIN
createjs.Sound.play("audioTrack"); // AND THEN PLAY IT
```

Comment: I think there is an open issue on the SoundJS github. Definitely on the roadmap!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting in a variable you can create an audio element, like this:

```
var snd = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64," + base64string);
snd.play();
```

Use de **HTMLAudioPlugin Class**

Here have more info, if you have problem with new Audio()
[play .wav sound file encoded in base64 with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762763/play-wav-sound-file-encoded-in-base64-with-javascript)

Comment: I know but than i can't play it by using createjs.Sound.play ([id])