# HTML 5 audio tag, what is the expected encoding?

Tags: html, audio, binary, base64

Can I specify the encoding of the file being received, is it only binary? Can I tell it it's expecting base64 etc?

Example use case :

```
<audio src="http://localhost:5000/test.wav" controls autoplay>
  <p>If your browser doesn't support the 'audio' element, it will display the content here between the opening and closing tags.</p>
</audio>
```

Comment: Do you need something like this [play .wav sound file encoded in base64 with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762763/play-wav-sound-file-encoded-in-base64-with-javascript)?

Comment: I have had a previous implementation using that method and I have encountered errors that lead me to try it this way.