# How to play selected file input with audio tag - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to play my selected file with audio tag:

```
  let [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();


  const changeHandlerFile = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
}

<input type="file" name="file" onChange={changeHandlerFile} accept="audio/*" />

<audio src={selectedFile} controls />
```

`selectedFile` variable is selected from an input file type.

but it doesn't play anything.

Comment: What does `selectedFile` result in? Is it a URL? What file does it try and load?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: How to read audio file and provide preview before upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64609592/react-how-to-read-audio-file-and-provide-preview-before-upload)

Comment: The duplicate link I shared should do the trick. The reason your current solution doesn't work as-is, is the fact that the file input itself doesn't really expose any information about the file other than file name. This is for security purposes, so a web app can't blindly read files from the client machine.